# TypeError: Expected a job store instance or a string, got NoneType instead

Tags: python, django, automation

Why I am getting this error?? I am trying to apscheduler in my django project. But the function is working very well. After sending some email it turns off automatically.

here is my code :

```
import logging
from django.conf import settings
from apscheduler.schedulers.blocking import BlockingScheduler
from django.core.management.base import BaseCommand
from django.core.mail import send_mail
from django.core.mail import EmailMessage
from ...models import *
from django_apscheduler.jobstores import DjangoJobStore
from apscheduler.triggers.cron import CronTrigger


logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)


class Command(BaseCommand):
    help = "Running in the dark :)"

    def send_email_to_registered_users(self):
        assessment = Assessment.objects.all()
        mail_subject = "Newsletter"
        message = "Welcome to our newsletter"
        for i in assessment:
            sender = i.email
            email_send = EmailMessage(mail_subject, message, to=[sender])
            email_send.send()
        print("email Sent")

    def handle(self, *args, **kwargs):
        scheduler = BlockingScheduler(timezone=settings.TIME_ZONE)
        scheduler.add_jobstore(DjangoJobStore(), "d")
        scheduler.add_jobstore(
            self.send_email_to_registered_users(),
            trigger=CronTrigger(second="*/10"),
            id="send_email_to_registered_users",
            max_instances=10,
        )
        logger.info("Printing Jobs!!! and sending!!")
        scheduler.start()
```

Answer (score 1):

After taking a quick glance at the [documentation](https://apscheduler.readthedocs.io/en/3.x/userguide.html#), I think this is the fix:

```py
    def handle(self, *args, **kwargs):
        scheduler = BlockingScheduler(timezone=settings.TIME_ZONE)
        scheduler.add_jobstore(DjangoJobStore(), "d")
        scheduler.add_job(  # I'm guessing you want to add a job
            self.send_email_to_registered_users,  # NOTE: no parenthesis
            trigger=CronTrigger(second="*/10"),
            id="send_email_to_registered_users",
            max_instances=10,
        )
        logger.info("Printing Jobs!!! and sending!!")
        scheduler.start()
```

PS. isn't it easier to create a crontab which runs the `python manage.py ...` command?